# Trying to use tap touch action on appium but is not working

Tags: java, appium-android

I'm new with Appium so for noob purpose I'm trying to tap an option (following my udemy course) and tried the following without success:

1. ```
    AndroidTouchAction t = new AndroidTouchAction (driver);
    t.tap (TapOptions.tapOptions().withElement(ElementOption.element(driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.TextView[@text= 'Expandable Lists']"))));
   ```
2. ```
    TouchActions t = new TouchActions(driver);
    WebElement expandList = driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.TextView[@text= 'Expandable Lists']");      
    t.doubleTap(expandList);
    t.perform();
   ```

Already import all what eclipse told me too and still...
Appium: 1.19.1
JRE: 1.8
Java client: 7.4.1
selenium-java: 3.141.59

Answer (score 1):

If you want to simply tap element, you can use the following code sample:

```java
TouchAction tapAction = new TouchAction(driver)
 .tap(tapOptions()
 .withElement(element(driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.TextView[contains(text(),'Expandable Lists')]"))))
tapAction.perform();
```

You can always check test examples in [appium-java-client](https://github.com/appium/java-client/blob/bcca20276191f98d9293974b6430cb97cb5e465c/src/test/java/io/appium/java_client/android/AndroidTouchTest.java) repo